# How to create wrapper around asynchronous loaded library

Tags: javascript

I'm using React and try to import some library that requires me to await it before I can start to use it. Something like this:

```
import theLibrary from ...

const myApp = () => {
  (async () => {
    await theLibrary.start
    const library = theLibrary
    const bla = library.methods.genBla()
    // ...
  })()

  // ...
}
```

I use this library somewhat often and I want to make a wrapper around it, so I won't get any delay on waiting for it to start all the time, but I don't know how I can achieve it. I would like to know what are the possible ways(OOP/FP) to do it and what is the best one in your opinion.

I want(perhaps you have better alternative?) to use it like this in my components:

```
import libWrapper from ...

const myApp = () => {
  const bla = libWrapper.methods.genBla()
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hook like:

```
async function getBlaLib() {
    await theLibrary.start
    const library = theLibrary
    const bla = library.methods.genBla()
    return bla
}

function useBlaLib() {
    const [bla, setBla] = React.useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    React.useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true)
      getBlaLib().then(bla => {
          setBla(bla)
          setLoading(false)
     })
    }, [])
    return [bla, loading]
}
```

Here is a more complete example: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-smoke-sguk21

Comment: Thanks, but what would be the way without using a custom hook?

Comment: Also, this will not preload the library to further use

Comment: 1. The problem is the lib loads asynchronously which means you will most likely need a 'useEffect` impl.  2. You could use `Context`.